# Parameter Substitution replace with Alternation (OR) |

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to replace a extension of a filename considering case but without success.

```
#!/bin/bash
pdf_file="/root/users/test.pdf"
jpg_file="${pdf_file/.pdf/.jpg}"
echo $jpg_file
```

I tried it, but it doesn't work:

```
jpg_file="${pdf_file/(.pdf|.PDF)/.jpg}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a glob pattern like this:

```
$ echo "${pdf_file/.[Pp][Dd][Ff]/.jpg}"
/root/users/test.jpg
```

If you use extended glob patterns (`shopt -s extglob)`, you could use this instead:

```
$ echo "${pdf_file/.@(PDF|pdf)/.jpg}"
/root/users/test.jpg
```

Or you could use the shell option to ignore case when matching:

```
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ pdf_file="/root/users/test.PDF"
$ echo "${pdf_file/.pdf/.jpg}"
/root/users/test.jpg
```

---

Remark valid for all three solutions: `${parameter/pattern/string}` replaces the pattern wherever it occurs, but the extension is likely at the end – we can make sure we'll only replace it at the end:

```
echo "${pdf_file%.[Pp][Dd][Ff]}.jpg"
```

which works in any POSIX shell, or

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${pdf_file%.@(PDF|pdf)}.jpg"
```

or

```
shopt -s nocasematch
pdf_file="/root/users/test.PDF"
echo "${pdf_file%.pdf}.jpg"
```

Comment: or POSIX compatible `jpg_file="${pdf_file%.[Pp][Dd][Ff]}.jpg"`

Comment: @LéaGris I was just about to add a remark about `%` ;)

Comment: Or while you know from start you want to replace the .extension `echo "${pdf_file%.*}.jpg"` and no fiddling with case match. ;D